# React Native Webview Clear Cache

Tags: react-native, webview

Is there a way to clear cache in webview for both ios and android?

I tried using @react-native-community_cookies, it works for ios, but for android Im getting this error when trying to run: A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_cookies'. > Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

Maybe any of you have suggestions how to fix this or know some other methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cookies for clear cache and write below function

```
import CookieManager from '@react-native-community/cookies';
CookieManager.clearAll(true)
```

The true param means that it will clear cookies for the webkit webview (which is what this library uses)

Comment: Yes, I tried using it, on ios it's ok, but when running android Im getting this "A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_cookies'. > Plugin with id 'maven' not found". Maybe you know the issue?

Comment: Then issue may be in gradle version check this https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies/issues/133

As per community they resolved in latest version 6.0.11, Try that version

Answer (score 0):

> Check out this library it does the job done.
>
> https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies

```
import CookieManager from '@react-native-cookies/cookies';


CookieManager.clearAll(true);
```